# Google sheets convert Decimal(0-100) to minutes(0-60)

Tags: google-sheets, time, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, duration

I have a spreadsheet that receives data from an RPA, this data is HH:MM, the output is based on how long a task has taken to perform.

example:

| Project | Time |
| --- | --- |
| Task 1 | 2:35 |
| Task 2 | 3:45 |

Where 2:35 is equal to 2 hours and 35 minutes.
The issue that i am having is that when I add these numbers google sheets displays it as 5:80, where it should be 6:20, as that is the actual amount of hours and minutes represented in the table. In other words I would like the decimal counter to stop at 60 and add new, not at a 100?

Anybody have an idea of how to achieve this? :)

-- Toby

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: @Calculuswhiz You are 100% correct, this was just a brainfart from me, i forgot i was working in another language than danish, so the delimiter had to be different in order for GS to understand the calculation as duration. Thank you and sorry :D

Answer (score 1):

In order for the duration formatting to work the delimeter must be the correct standard according to the language you are working in.